Dynamic Knock Back Force Based on Collider Velocity
I'm making a game prototype in Godot. My player character is a ship that moves around in 3D space without gravity. I have some simple code that adds a knock back force to the player on collisions based on the collision normal.
I would like the knock back force to be based on the velocity of the colliding object.
So, if the colliding body is a static object, a base knock back force is applied.
But, if the colliding body is, say, a moving player, that player's velocity increases the base knock back force to be applied to our player.
Being sorta bad at math, I haven't quite managed to get this working quite right.
Here is a snippet of my current collision/knock back code:
var relative_velocity = velocity # If collider is static
if collider is CharacterBody3D:
    relative_velocity = velocity - collider.velocity
    knockback_velocity = (collision_normal * knockback_force) + relative_velocity


How does the behaviour with the current code differ from what you want? What should answers focus on improving about the behaviour?

The answer I'm looking for is more so, "would this code result in the behavior described?".
Because, the current code doesn't work as expected, in the sense that only the arbitrary value of around 150 for knockback_force works, relatively well. Anything below that, and the physics of the player completely break. I was hoping that my math was missing something crucial that would explain this odd behavior.

It's not clear what you mean by "completely break". The math you've shown does create a knock back "based on the velocity of the colliding object", in that the colliding object's velocity is added to this object's. If the result isn't what you want, we'll need you to be more specific about what you mean by "based on". What specific behaviour do you want to see, and what is different about what you have now?

Thanks for the reply, and sorry for communicating well what I was asking. But now I think there were just some issues related to how I was using the CharacterBody3D node. But my issue is no longer a problem, since I've achieved what I wanted with a different node (RigidBody3D).
In any case, thanks for confirming that the math did, in fact, work as described. I used the same equation for the RigidBody3D collision handling and it works perfectly.

Want to post your solution as an Answer below that you can mark Accepted, or would you prefer to delete your question if you no longer need help with it?
